# Отобразить четные и нечетные числа по отдельности из массива Java

Tags: java

Не получается вывести четные и нечетные числа на одной линии:

```
int n = key.nextInt();        
int[] a = new int[n];   
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {   
    a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);    
    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");   
}   
System.out.println();  
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {   
    if (a[i]%2==0) {  
        System.out.println("even="+a[i]+" ");   
    }   
}   
System.out.println();   
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {   
    if (a[i]%2!=0) {   
        System.out.println("odd="+a[i]+" ");  
    }  
}
```

Направьте в нужном направлении.

Comment: я удалил метку [tag:arraylist] пока вы не скажите причем тут она

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `println`, видимо, надо использовать `print`. Тогда всё будет печататься на одной линии.